# Android InstantApp fails to open Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-instant-apps

When I launch my android app in InstantApp mode, it fails to open camera even after granting relevant Camera permission.

I am creating Android Instant App where a user can capture an image and upload on the server.

I am using Camera2 API. InstantApp doesn't allow `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent as Android doesn't permit external storage permission.

The app is able to open Camera after asking relevant permission if I launch in normal (non-instant) mode.

But When I launch in InstantApp mode, it fails to open the camera. I see these logs in logcat.

> 09-26 07:33:29.104 7846-7846/com.project.snapdrive I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
>
> 09-26 07:33:29.174 7846-7846/com.project.snapdrive I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
>
> 09-26 07:33:29.182 7846-7891/com.project.snapdrive **W/Camera: An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: -74 (Not a data message)**

If you want to have a look at code, My Project is [here](https://github.com/vikash-singh/instant-app).

I am using **emulator Nexus 5X, Android 6.0, API 23.**

Comment: Try launching the same app in your phone.

Comment: I don't have Pixel or Nexus. I have other variants but those are not whitelisted by Google.

Comment: I ran your instant app and got `java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service` error. There is an open bug about CAMERA permission denial in instant apps https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66942980

Comment: Instant app works with the standard camera intent https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html. I created a sample app with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and confirmed that photos could be taken from instant apps with the camera app.

Comment: @JuliaK It didn't work for me. Could you please post your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829710/instant-apps-camera-intent), if you are able to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: @Vikash You know what, it only works on O for me atm. All I did was copy the code from “Take a photo with a camera app” and “Get the thumbnail” at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html The camera opened and I was able to get a result from it, no camera permission needed. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66942980#comment3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug reproducible on the Android O. It could be reproduced as well with the sample  Camera2Basic project adapted into an Instant App:
 [Sample code](https://github.com/Idolon-V/InstantApp-Camera)

Can you check status of [bug on the Google tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66942980) for update of this bug.

**UPDATE** 
**=======**
**This issue has been fixed and rolled out on 8.1** devices already.
We are working with our partners to roll out the fix into the update for 8.0 devices.
We expect those updates to be rolled out in the coming months.